# Export symbols in a python namespace package's __init__ file

Tags: python, packaging

I'm currently in the process of breaking up a large package in smaller packages. I want to keep the same API that I've been using for the big monolithic package.

The package layout is something similar to:

```
company/
    _models/
        __init__.py
        model1.py
        model2.py
    models.py
    __init__.py
```

Where `company._models/__init__.py` imports the models from `model1.py` and `model2.py`, and `models.py` has `from ._models import *`

This structure allows me to access all the exported models via `company.models`.

What I would like to do is be able to split this up into smaller packages using namespace packages, but keep the same API. So I would have two packages with something similar to the following layout

```
# package1
company/
    _models/
        model1.py
# package2
company/
    _models.
        model2.py
```

My understanding of namespace packages is that I can get the two packages to overlap, but since there can't be arbitrary code in the `__init__.py` files, that I can't have the `import` lines.

Is what I want to do possible at all?

One possible solution I see, is that instead of these being separate "packages", they're more like plugins to a core package, and I would have some kind of `register(plugin)` function that would add the plugin's exports to the core package's namespace.

Comment: "but since there can't be arbitrary code in the `__init__.py` files" How come?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#namespace-packages

Comment: @Richard That link 404's :/

Comment: @JamesMills the distribute package has been deprecated in favour of setuptools, I guess the following corresponds http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages

Comment: @Naddiseo Yeah I've realized after more reading and thinking about it that this isn't possible in any implementation.